# Null selectedDate in QCalendarWidget

Tags: null, pyqt

I want to set selectedDate to null in QCalendarWidget in order to force the user to manually select the date each and every time he opens the form. Any ways of doing this?

Comment: This makes no sense. What month/year would the calendar show for a "null" date (whatever that is)? And what would your program do if the user didn't select anything? Why can't you just initialize the calendar with an appropriate default?

Comment: A current month perhaps, without any particular date selected. I want the user to make a ***conscious*** decisions selecting a date each and every time and have the form fail otherwise, as it shows that using a default date leads to too many human errors in this business environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by setting stylesheet to the following on start up:

```
QCalendarWidget QAbstractItemView {
    selection-color: black;
    selection-background-color: white;}
```

This way even though a date is selected at the start, user can not see the selection and is forced to do it.

Answer (score 0):

To register a positive user response in a calendar widget, connect an appropriate handler to either its [activated](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcalendarwidget.html#activated) signal, or its [selectionChanged](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcalendarwidget.html#selectionChanged) signal.

The first of these fires when a date is either double-clicked or return/enter is pressed; the second fires whenever the selected date is changed by navigation with the mouse or keyboard (or programmatically).

So your form could be initialized with an internal variable set `None`, and the signal handler would then set the variable to the date selected by the user. Alternatively, you could have a confirmation button that is initially disabled, and then re-enabled by the signal handler.